# RBAC configuring on solaris 11.4

Tags: solaris, rbac

Hi everyone I am facing some issues on solaris 11.4 implementing RBAC. I created user and role and giving profiles for the roles, but I can execute the command. I drop my RBAC Configuration below.

```
$useradd -m test

$passwd test

$roleadd -c "User Administrator role,User Management role local" \-m -K profiles="User Security,User Management"  sec1

$passwd sec1

$usermode -R +sec1 test
```

I login by my new test user and my role sec1 successfully. I can create user, give password, delete user and password. The role can not add new role.

```
sec1@:~$ usermod -R +sec1 test

/usr/lib/passmgmt: Permission denied. Cannot set roles to sec1, requires sec1 role.

UX: usermod: ERROR: Permission denied.

UX: usermod: ERROR: Cannot update system - login cannot be modified.
```

How can I use usermod and rolemod for the user? If any one can help me? To which solaris profiles can have access to role related to the user?

Answer (score 0):

Seems that it is some bug in usermod command while it is running from role (not user). I was succeed to delegate this privilege via user-to-user (without role)

As root user give privilege to test user directly:

```
/usr/sbin/usermod -K profiles="User Security,User Management" test
```

Also create an other user for testing

```
useradd -m testuseradm
```

Then login as `test` and use this privilege:

```
pfexec /usr/sbin/usermod -K profiles="User Security,User Management" testuseradm
```

Optionally you could add `-K auth_profiles="User Security,User Management"` to ask `testuseradm` to enter his password again.

The main difference of user and role - the role could not login directly. So you may create some shared user account and introduce it as role to your colleges as workaround.